# Functional Programming in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

Is there a good library for functional programming in Java?

I'm looking for stuff like [Predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) and [List.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) (as a static method). Not complicated to implement, but it would be nice to find a reusable library here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[FunctionalJava](http://functionaljava.org/) is the best known library; it makes use of Java closures ([BGGA](http://javac.info)) for examples:

```
final Array<Integer> a = array(1, 2, 3);  
final Array<Integer> b = a.map({int i => i + 42});  
arrayShow(intShow).println(b); // {43,44,45}
```

**EDIT**

Check also [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/).

**Further EDIT**

BGGA is entirely optional. It just makes for nicer syntax.

Comment: But BGGA is not actually in Java. So this won't compile, right?

Comment: BGGA is available as a precompiler that translates {int i => i + 42} into new F<Integer, Integer>() { public Integer f(Integer i) {return i + 42; }}. The latter will compile with any old Java.

Comment: right, it is a little frustrating indeed

Comment: Also, the source code is readable and embeddable.  I was able to take out some of the classes without the full blown library and make use of functional java.

Answer (score 30):

[**Scala**](http://www.scala-lang.org/) is a functional programming language that is fully compatible with Java (runs through the JVM). It offers a beautiful mix of object-oriented and functional techniques along with many improvements over Java in generics and concurrency. [Some even say it could replace Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995953/scala-the-java-of-the-future)

Answer (score 27):

## Java Libraries

There are libraries that can help you do this, by already doing the legwork for you and hiding the arcane things:

#### Mature / Established Libraries

- [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/)
- [Google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)
- [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)

#### More Obscure / Experimental Libraries

- [Fun4J](http://www.fun4j.org/)
- [JCurry](http://code.google.com/p/jcurry/)
- [OCaml-Java](http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/)
- [Jambda](http://www.agical.com/jambda/)
- [Bolts](https://bitbucket.org/stepancheg/bolts/)

These will allow you to write Java code with a more functional approach and possibly more familiar syntax and semantic, as you'd expect from an FP-competent language. Within reason, that is.

### JVM Languages

And obviously, you can **implement** a functional language on top of Java. So that you can then use that one as your FP language. Which is a bit of a higher-level of abstraction than what you asked for, but relatively within context (though I'm cheating a bit here, granted).

For instance, check out:

#### Quite Mature Languages

- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)

#### Less Mature or More Obscure Languages

- [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege/)
- [Jaskell](http://jaskell.codehaus.org/)

## Further Reading

You may also want to read or watch these articles or videos:

- [Functional Progamming in the Java Language](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-fp/index.html), [IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/) (2004)
- [Functional Programming Java](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/95), [Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/) (2004)
- [Functional Programming: a Pragmatic Introduction](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Programming-A-Pragmatic-Introduction), [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/)/CodePalousa (2011)

---

*Taken from my [P.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) answer to **"[Is Functional Programming Possible in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101352/is-functional-programming-possible-in-java/101361#101361)"***

Comment: +1 Excellent "Further Reading" Links!!!

Answer (score 13):

[Google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) has a decent selection of functional-programming style utility methods. 
Some classes of interest are Iterables, Iterators, Function, Functions, etc

It also has a bunch of collection classes as well!

Comment: The library is now superseded by Guava.

Answer (score 12):

[Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) is one that's worth taking a look at and [FunctionalJ](http://functionalj.sourceforge.net/) is another.

Comment: So .. which one?
Also, for the lazy among us, can they be used without Java closures? 

(Assuming I only want a library, not something that forces me to use a different compiler)

Comment: Functional Java is just a library, but it works with the BGGA closure syntax if you want to use that.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a pure Java solution check out lambdaj

http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

Besides the possibility to define and use closure in a DSL-style, it also allows to manipulate collections in a functional way, without explicitly write closures or loops

Comment: LambdaJ seems to be more popular than functionaljava.

Answer (score 4):

[Jambda](http://github.com/brolund/jambda/tree/master) is another FP-library. From the [documentation](http://www.agical.com/jambda/):

> Jambda is an attempt to provide the
>   Java(TM) world with tools and concepts
>   from functional programming (FP).
>
> The goals are several:
>
> - To provide Java programmers with expressive FP constructs
> - To provide a bridge for Java programmers into the FP-world
> - To see how far Java and generics can be stretched
>
> This
>   document is an attempt to introduce
>   Java programmers into the FP world,
>   and at the same time explain some (or
>   most) of the features in Jambda.

Answer (score 4):

Apache Commons has some functional-ish code in it. See for example, the [Predicate](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/p/org.apache.commons.collections/c/Predicate) interface.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) has functional:

- collection operations
- concurrency constructs (Futures)

Answer (score 4):

Or download OpenJDK 8 to try out Lambda expressions the way they will become in Java 8. Among others, the collection APIs are adjusted to support a functional style. See 
http://macgyverdev.blogspot.se/2012/10/functional-programming-in-java.html
for examples of new collection APIs and comparisons with Guava, LambdaJ and FunctionalJava.

Answer (score 4):

Scala was mentioned here, but there's a lot lighter and more Java compatible language: [Xtend](http://xtend-lang.org). It compiles to plain Java and uses the same type system. It has great Eclipse support. You can mix `.java` and `.xtend` files in a single project.

Sample code:

```
def static void main(String[] args) {
    val s = #[1,2,3].map[it+43].join(", ")
    println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although Functional Java is the most popular but i'll suggest you to try Google guava lib.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/