# Extraction of list of objects from list of objects in Java

Tags: java

Suppose that you have a class `A` like follows:

```
public class A{
  private B b;

  public B getB(){return b;}
}
```

Then, you have a list of `A` objects and you want to create another list that contains the related `B` objects, i.e.

```
List<A> listOfA=...
List<B> listOfB = extractFrom(listOfA, "getB");
```

Exists a library that does the magic described by function `extractFrom`? Maybe it uses reflection, I don't know.
Or, maybe the library relies on an `Extractor` interface that uses generics, e.g.

```
public interface Extractor<T,V>{

  public T extract(V source);
}
```

and then one does:

```
Extractor ex=...;
List<B> listOfB = extractFrom(listOfA, ex);
```

PS: The title is horrible! Please, edit the title so that it becomes more meaningfull.

Comment: AFAIK no, there's no such library.

Comment: Just as a hint: You are looking for the equivalent in Java of Python's map(function, iterable, ...) function, described here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Ok, I will implement it from myself. Usually I don't like to reinvent the well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a solution. This uses [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

You need a `Function<A, B>`, then apply that function using `Lists.transform()`:

```
final Function extractB = new Function<A, B>()
{
    @Override
    public B apply(final A input)
    {
        return input.getB();
    }
}

// And then:

final List<B> listOfB = Lists.transform(listOfA, extractB);
```

Note that Java 8 will have `Function`, among other niceties "invented" by Guava (`Predicate` is another example).

Comment: Oh! Great! I was very surprised to discover that none already implemented such a useful utility! Thank you!

Comment: Guava is a gold mine. Just Use It(tm) :p

Comment: I know, I use it! But I don't know all the utilities. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is know as map.

Here in SO have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907394/java-is-there-a-map-function)

In addition you can do with the apache commons using [transformers](http://apachecommonstipsandtricks.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/examples-of-functors-transformers.html)

By example:

```
Collection<B> bs = CollectionUtils.collect(collectionOfA, new Transformer() {
    public Object transform(Object a) {
        return ((A) a).getB();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. I saw a time ago an implementation of apache commons that use generics, but I don't found the link.