# How to create a ArrayList of strings from a ArrayList of user data type

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<MyDataType> pList;` where MyDataType is a simple class like below:

```
class MyDataType {
    int modified;
    String name;
}
```

If my pList has size of 10 and if i want to retrieve ArrayList of names for all objects in it, how do I do that?

For example

```
ArrayList<String> myNames = new ArrayList<pList...>();
```

I want to know what the right hand side of the above statement should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to iterate over pList and add each name one by one.

Comment: Hi Winzu, I was thinking the same, but still is there any way to initialize it apart from iterating ?

Comment: I don't know any syntax that would do what you want.
But there are multiple examples of what you need in the answer now ;)

Comment: Thanks for all others who gave me quick replies

Answer (score 2):

Declare a `List<String>`  than iterate over `pList` and add `name` to `names list`.

```
 List<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
 for(MyDataType dt:pList){
 names.add(dt.getName())
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++)
{
    names.add(pList.get(i).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
List<MyDataType > pList=new ArrayList<MyDataType >();

List<String> myNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (MyDataType myDataType : pList) {           
    myNames.add(myDataType.getName());      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some [functional ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907394/java-is-there-a-map-function) to do this such as Guava, but that comes with some major performance concerns.  Stick to the basics and iterate through the list.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for(MyDataType element:pList){
    //hopefully this would use an accessor element.getName()
    names.add(element.name); 
}
```