# Create java collection with n clones of an object

Tags: java, collections

In Java, is there a one-line way to create a collection that is initialized with *n* clones of an object?

I'd like the equivalent of this:

- `foo = vector<vector<int> >(10);` c++, creates 10 different empty vectors
- `[ [] for i in range(10) ]` Python, an array of 10 distinct empty arrays
- `Array.new(10) { [] }` Ruby, same as Python

In Java, I've only found

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >(Collections.nCopies(10, new ArrayList<Integer>()))
```

However, this is *not* equivalent to the other examples, because the lists alias.

Is there a way to create an array of distinct object clones, without using a for loop, and preferably without resorting to [external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907394/java-is-there-a-map-function)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Java 8 you could use its streams:

```
Stream.generate(ArrayList<Integer>::new)
    .limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The [`Stream.generate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) method takes a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) that knows how to produce a value and generates an infinite stream of those values (each value is obtained by calling the supplier again, so they are all different, unlike `Collections.nCopies()`). Placing a `limit()` on the stream and then collecting the results to a list thus yields a list of distinct entries.

Note that starting in Java 16 `Stream` has a `toList()` method, so this can become a little cleaner:

```
Stream.generate(ArrayList<Integer>::new).limit(10).toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to pass in **constructor arguments** (which is not possible with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26854032/3863059) and suppliers as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251629/java-8-supplier-with-arguments-in-the-constructor)) - you can use the following (I do not know if there is a better solution but it at least fulfilled my needs):

```
final List<MyObject> result = IntStream.range(0, n)
   .mapToObj(index -> new MyObject(...))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

whereas you would replace `n` by the number of elements you want to fill the list with and `MyObject` and `new MyObject(...)` with your type and ctor-call respectively.

This creates a stream of integers ranging from 0 to n (n exclusive), maps every "index" to any object returned by the lambda-expr. in `mapToObj` and finally converts the stream to a list which will contain `n` distinct instances of `MyObject`.

Comment: This is certainly best if you need the index for something, and probably otherwise too, but it's worth noting that the accepted answer could take other arguments.  `Stream.generate(() -> new MyObject(someFinalVar)).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1):

Even with the introduction of Java 8 [`Supplier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), there is unfortunately not a succinct one-liner like `nCopies`. To be honest, I don't know why. (Though @DavidConrad has shown that `Stream` can do this.)

You can easily *create* one yourself, for example:

```
public static <E, L extends List<? super E>> L fill(
        L list, Supplier<E> sup, int n) {
    for(; n > 0; --n)
        list.add(sup.get());
    return list;
}
```

Call like:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = ArrayUtils.fill(
    new ArrayList<>, ArrayList<Integer>::new, 10
);
```

For arrays, there is the new method [`Arrays#setAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

```
Integer[] oneToTen = new Integer[10];
Arrays.setAll(oneToTen, i -> i + 1);
List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(oneToTen);
```

But it is a `void` method so it can't be used in a single statement. (Personal remark: why can't Java API be fluid?)

Prior to Java 8 there is not a library method to do this and it is more cumbersome to create one. Since `clone` is protected, it cannot be invoked generically. Reflection can do it but reflection is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could write `ArrayList<Integer>::new`. That simplifies my Supplier a bit in my code. +1, thanks.

Comment: @DavidConrad Feel free to steal it from me. ; )

Comment: Just did. This is what I love about StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

- `vector<vector<int> > = new vector<vector<int> >(10);`
  Is not syntactically correct but lets say you meant `vector<vector<int> > foo(10);`.  You are using the [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)  which will initialize the container size and then initialize each element to a copy of the `value_type` parameter (or the default constructor if you didn't specify anything).  This will use a loop.
- `[ [] for i in range(10) ]` and `Array.new(10) { [] }` are just doing the looping on 1 line and copying an empty list type structure in.

As you indicated the `nCopies` method is not equivalent because the result is immutable and you are not creating copies (or clones).  The reference to the same element is used when every index is accessed.  See the [openjdk copies implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.nCopies%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) for reference.

Some of the difficulties with java is there is no guarantee of a default constructor like in C++ and the syntax is a bit different than most scripting languages. This may be a good opportunity to take a second and understand what is going on under the covers to ensure your solution is not doing more work than necessary.  Some follow up questions to ask yourself:

- What other construct (besides a loop did you have in mind)?  I believe there will be a loop at some level.
- How do you really want to be initializing the ArrayList objects inside the outer ArrayList?  For example what size do you want them to be?  Should they be initially populated with anything?  How big do you expect them to grow?  Do they need to be uniform size or does it makes sense for some to be bigger/smaller?  Does it make sense to lazily initialize these lists?

To help answer these questions it may be good practice to write your own generic static initializer for your use case.  After you get the simple case down if your use case varies it may make your solution more generic to use the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to initialize your inner lists.  As you can see there is a good deal of issues to consider and in the simple case you may just end up with something like:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> newListofLists(int outerSize, int innerSize, T value) {
    List<List<T>> outer = new ArrayList<List<T>>(outerSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < outer.size(); ++i) {
        List<T> inner = new ArrayList<T>(innerSize);
        outer.add(inner);
        for (int j = 0; j < inner.size(); ++j) {
            inner.add(value);
        }
    }
    return outer;
}
```

This can then be used to initialize your lists in one line like:

```
List<List<Integer>> myList = newListofLists(10, 5, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I corrected my C++ syntax. Regarding your other comments: I don't necessarily consider a list comprehension a loop -- even though they are semantically equivalent. And the C++ version may well use memcpy behind the curtains, which is a loop (or a special CPU instruction?) but also somewhat different.

Anyway; this was more about succinct code than other considerations... but it's good you bring attention to them.

Comment: You could always use [Arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) as an alternative to the inner loop.  However the benefits of this may be limited by heap memory.  Use of a direct ByteBuffer may allow for operations like memcpy to be directly used.