# Java generic object with lambda expressions

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently working my way thorough Java Core book and I'm in the generic chapter. I can't grasp one thing here. As book states you cannot make a new object out of T in generic class, so this is not possible

```
public foo() { first = new T(); second = new T(); } //ERROR
```

What you can do is use functional interface and lambda expression with reference to constructor like this

```
foo<String> f = foo.makeFoo(String::new)
```

---

```
public static <T> foo<T> makeFoo(Supplier<T> constr)
{
    return new foo<>(constr.get(), constr.get());
}
```

And it's great, working as expected, but only with String, if I want to use with any other object, for example wrapped simple type Integer it's not possible. It gives me this error

```
Error:(35, 38) java: method makeFoo in class generic.foo<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.util.function.Supplier<T>
found: Integer::new
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(argument mismatch; incompatible parameter types in method reference)
```

It seems only working with String and I have no idea why, I thought that it would work for every object

I'm trying to create all those objects on correct classes

```
  foo<String> fString = foo.makeFoo(String::new); //Works
  foo<Integer> fInteger = foo.makeFoo(Integer::new); //Doesn't work
  foo<Double> fDouble = foo.makeFoo(Double::new); //Doesn't work
```

---

EDIT

Actually this works with custom objects, only wrapped simple types won't compile

```
foo<MyCustomObject> fCustom = foo.makeFoo(MyCustomObject::new); //Works
```

Comment: The type of the variable `f` is `foo<String>`, so obviously it expects that the supplier returns a `String` object. Change it to `foo<Integer>` if you're giving it a supplier that returns an `Integer` object.

Comment: I'm doing exactly that and this gives cannot applied error.

          foo<Integer> fInteger = foo.makeFoo(Integer::new);

Comment: @MTomczyński I've rejected your edit of my answer as there was to much text/code I did not write. I think it would be better if you would have posted it as your own answer to your question, this is absolutely appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to `String`, there is no no-arg constructor of `Integer`. So `Integer::new` is not a `Supplier<Integer>`. `makeFoo(Object::new)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

As lexicore pointed we cannot make expression Integer::new, due to no no-arg constructor of Integer object. Correct syntax with integer can be as simple as this, where arg being int variable

```
foo<Integer> f = foo.makeFoo(() -> (arg));
```

Wrapping in new Integer(arg) is unnecessary here.

More info on the topic: [Java 8 Supplier with arguments in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251629/java-8-supplier-with-arguments-in-the-constructor)