# Why does a method reference to ctor that "throws" ... throw as well?

Tags: java, constructor, method-reference

I am looking for an elegant way to create a factory for dependency injection. In my case, the factory simply has to call a one-argument constructor. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31258084/1531124) outlining how to use a `Function<ParamType, ClassToNew>` for such purposes.

But my problem is: in my case, my ctor declares to throw some checked exception.

What I don't get: creating that *Function* using a method reference to that constructor doesn't work. As in:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Mcve {        
    public Mcve(String s) throws Exception {
        // whatever
    }        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<String, Mcve> mcveFactory = Mcve::new;
    }
}
```

tells me about "Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception" for `Mcve::new`. Although this code is **not** invoking the constructor.

Two questions:

- why that error? The above code does **not** invoke the ctor (yet)?
- are there any elegant ways to solve this puzzle? ( simply adding `throws Exception` to my `main()` does **not** help )

Comment: Actually, when I try to compile this it does not say "unhandled exception", but "incompatible thrown types Exception in method reference", which makes more sense.

Comment: Also, highly related: [Java 8 Lambda function that throws exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18198176/1639625)

Comment: @tobias_k To be precise: that error message is what IntelliJ is telling me. (Unhandled exception ... )

Comment: "that error message" Which one, the one from your question or the one from my comment?

Comment: @tobias_k The one message I have in my question and that you quoted in your comment? Or are there others? ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to provide a custom interface `ThrowingFunction` which has one method that throws `Exception`.

```
public interface ThrowingFunction<ParameterType, ReturnType> {
    ReturnType invoke(ParameterType p) throws Exception;
}

public class Mcve {
    public Mcve(String s) throws Exception {
        // whatever
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThrowingFunction<String, Mcve> mcveFactory = Mcve::new;
    }
}
```

Using this approach results in calling `mcveFactory.invoke("lalala");` forcing you to handle the exception thrown by the constructor.

Reason for the error is that the actual function reference you want to store  (not 100% sure about the terminology) throws an exception and therefore the types simply do not match up. *If* you could store `Mcve::new` inside a function then whoever calls the function no longer *knows* an `Exception` can be thrown. What would then happen if the exception would actually be thrown? Both throwing the exception and discarding it do not work.

---

Alternative: if you need to actually retrieve a `Function<String, Mcve>` in the end then you need to write a function (or lambda) that invokes the constructor, catches the exception and either discards it or rethrows it wrapped inside a unchecked `RuntimeException`.

```
public class Mcve {
    public Mcve(String s) throws Exception {
        // whatever
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<String, Mcve> mcveFactory = parameter -> {
            try {
                return new Mcve(parameter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); // or ignore
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

I would argue that the error message itself is at least a bit misleading since you normally see it when actually invoking the method. I can certainly understand the confusion resulting in the first sub-question. It would be clearer (sadly not possible) to state something like

> Incompatible types `Function<String,Mcve>` vs. `Function<String,Mcve> throws Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do that just recently... If you *can* change the class definition, you could use the infamous sneaky throws way of doing things:

```
static class OneArg {

    private final String some;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E extends Exception> OneArg(String some) throws E {
        try {
            this.some = some;
            // something that might throw an Exception... 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw (E) e;
        }
    }

    public String getSome() {
        return some;
    }
}

Function<String, OneArg> mcveFactory = OneArg::new;
```

Comment: I only knew [`@SneakyThrows`](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) from lombok, had no idea you could do it with plain java, that looks incredibly hacky but interesting. +1 for the sake of learning something new.

Comment: Nice idea, but not really: your hack basically "invalidates" the throws clause. So the code still says "throws SomeCheckedExceptions" but code calling the ctor isn't forced to try/catch any more. In that sense, this goes along the lines that Y_xxx proposed initially: to simply drop the "throws" clause somehow.

Comment: @GhostCat I've added one more option - in case you mind and disagree with it - I might delete it...

Comment: I’d have split the code into the constructor with the `throws Exception` clause and a helper method doing the sneaky throw with the unchecked cast for clarity, but anyway, that’s the working solution; afaik the only one remaining that is not depreated/defunc in the recent Java version. Well, it would generate a warning if it wasn’t suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this for a while and indeed - if you want to have a `Function` that declares clearly your intention, I think that you need to have a `Function` that would extend the `java.util.Function`, something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {

    R applyWithExc(T t) throws Exception;

    @Override
    default R apply(T t) {
        try {
            return applyWithExc(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can btw choose which method you call when you define your constructor reference - the one that would throw an `Exception` and one that would silently wrap it with a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: One other approach, worth an upvote. But I think it isn't too practical in the real world - as you would need a special interface for each different checked exception you are dealing with. And then: in the end the whole function thing is more of a "byproduct" - in the end, it is about writing down a *factory*. A factory that has type "Function" and that you call with "apply" to create a new instance ... doesn't exactly fit my rules for clear, speaking names ;-)