# Mocking locally created objects in java using Mockito2

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods, testability

I am writing module tests for a project using testng and Mockito2. I want to mock a few methods which make outbound requests. Now, the object to mock is created locally within another object's method. So, if I have say, 4 classes, A, B, C and D, such that A creates an object of type B, B creates an object of type C and so on, and object of type D is to be mocked, I see I have two options to mock it.

Option 1 is to spy on objects of type A,B,C and inject spy of B into A and C into B and finally inject mock of of D into C during object creation. Following is an example.

```
class A {
        public B createB()
        {
            retrun new B();
        }
        public void someMethod ()
        {
            B b = createB();
        }
    }
```

In this way I can can spy on A and inject mock object for B when createB is called. This way I can ultimately mock D.

Option 2 is to not mock intermittent classes and directly have a Factory class like the one below:

```
class DFactory {
    private static D d;
    static public void setD (D newD)
    {
         d = newD;
    }
    public static D getD()
    {
        if (d!=null)
        {
            return d;
        } else
        {
            return new D();
        }
    }
}
```

The above option is simple, but I am not sure if this is the right thing to do as it creates more static methods, something that should be avoided, I believe.

I would like to know which method should be preferred and if there is some other alternative.

Please note that I do not wish to use powermockito or any other such frameworks which encourage bad code design. I want to stick to mockito2. I am fine with refactoring my code to make it more testable.

Comment: Recommend you read up on the concept of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now, with A creating B and B creating C and C creating D, all of that creation are *implementation details you can't see or change*, specifically *the creation of dependency objects*.

You are admirably avoiding the use of PowerMockito, and you are also admirably interested in refactoring your code to handle this change well, which means *delegating the choice of D to the creator of A*. Though I understand that you only really mean for this choice to happen in testing, the language doesn't know that; you are choosing a different implementation for the dependency, and taking the choice away from C's implementation. This is known as an *inversion of control*, or *dependency injection*. (You've probably heard of them before, but I introduce those terms at the end because they typically associated with weight and frameworks that aren't really necessary for this conversation right now.)

It's a little trickier because it looks like you don't just need an implementation of D, but that you need to create new implementations of D. That makes things a little harder, but not by much, especially if you are able to use Java 8 lambdas and method references. Anywhere below that you see a reference to `D::new`, that's a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to D's constructor [that could be accepted as a `Supplier<D>` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31251629/1426891).

I would restructure your class in one of the following ways:

- Construct A like `new A()`, but leave the control over the implementation of D for when you actually call A, like `aInstance.doSomething(new D())` or `aInstance.doSomething(D::new)`. This means that C would delegate to the caller every single time you call a method, giving more control to the callers. Of course, you might choose to offer an overload of `aInstance.doSomething()` that internally calls `aInstance.doSomething(new D())`, to make the default case easy.
- Construct A like `new A(D::new)`, where A calls `new B(dSupplier)`, and B calls `new C(dSupplier)`. This makes it harder to substitute B and C in unit tests, but if the only likely change is to have the network stack represented by D, then you are only changing your code as required for your use-case.
- Construct A like `new A(new B(new C(D::new)))`. This means that A is only involved with its direct collaborator B, and makes it much easier to substitute any implementation of B into A's unit tests. This assumes that A only needs a single instance of B without needing to create it, which may not be a good assumption; if all classes need to create new instances of their children, A would accept a `Supplier<B>`, and A's construction would look like `new A(() -> new B(() -> new C(D::new)))`.  This is compact, but complicated, and you might choose to create an AFactory class that manages the creation of A and the configuration of its dependencies.

If the third option is tempting for you, and you think you might want to automatically generate a class like AFactory, consider looking into a *dependency injection framework* like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) or [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger).