# How to apply a function to an array element wise in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have 3 functions, something like `y_1(x) = x^2`, `y_2(x) = x+1` and `y_3(x) = x/5`.
How do I apply these functions to any multidimensional float array in an element wise fashion?

Now given that I have the functions `y_1`, `y_2` and `y_3`, what is a function that applies an arbitrary function to a float array of any size and shape?

I tried creating a function applier that takes in any function and then applying it to every element in a double loop for the 2 dimensional case but I cannot even get the function applier to take another function as input.

I tried doing the following

```
public float[][] elemen_wise_function(  float[][] x,
                                        int Size_axis_0,
                                        int Size_axis_1,
                                        Callable<> myFunc) {

    float[][] Constructed_array = new float[Size_axis_0][Size_axis_1];
    for (int i=0; i<Size_axis_0; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Size_axis_1; j++) {
            Constructed_array[i][j] = (float) myFunc(x[i][j]) ;
        }
    }
    return Constructed_array;
}
```

But this fails because I cannot find a way to pass `myFunc` to `elemen_wise_function`.

Comment: `map` is the typical function to do this, although you'll need to use streams for that in Java. You could also just loop over the array using a standard `for` loop, and produce a new array using the loop.

Comment: do you want something like `Arrays.map`? possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907448/10625458

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: And to take a function as an argument, look into the `Function` type. This question is a little broad though, as there's many ways to do what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know of any examples online?

Comment: Although the question is slightly vague, the simplest way I could see it is to iterate through your multi-dimensional array and use each element as your 'X'. Use Random to determine which function shall be applied to your float and call it, if that's what you want it to do. You could always create an object that has a float field and a String to hold a function if you do not want to do the math directly to your elements.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I updated my question to show what I tried in the 2D case. Because I won't be working with more than 5D I could just define a function for every dimensions, even though it's ugly. It's just that I cannot get it to work even if the dimension is set.

Comment: So that's just a [`UnaryOperator<Float>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) then?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Do you have an example of how to use that? You seem to think it's trivial but I just don't get what I should do with that. Where would you insert that in what I tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite cool, you can pass a lambda (since java 8):

```
public float[][] elemen_wise_function(float[][] x,
                                      Function<Float, Float> f) {

    float[][] Constructed_array = new float[x.length][x[0].length];
    for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++) {
            Constructed_array[i][j] = f.apply(x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return Constructed_array;
}
```

Then you can pass any function defined as lambda, for example:

```
Function<Float, Float> fun = x -> 2 * x;
```

Also one note - use camelCase in java for method names;)

Comment: Using `Function<Float, Float>` has a disadvantage of forcing auto-boxing to `Float` objects (and back to `float`) which is extra overhead.

Comment: That is true. It can be visible in costly operations.

Comment: I like that you took 2 inputs out of my function! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, those were redundant, as they could be easily derived:)

Comment: As a followup question, how would I specify a function with multiple inputs? So to replace Function<Float, Float>, what would be correct syntax to indicate Function<Float, [Float, Float]>?

Comment: No, then simply use `BiFunction` and declare your lambda for example as follows: `BiFunction<Float, Float, Float> bf = (i, e) -> i * e;`. This is equivalent to function z(x, y) = x * y.

Comment: `UnaryOperator` is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to declare myFunc as [`UnaryOperator<Float>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html).

```
public float[][] elemen_wise_function(float[][] x, int Size_axis_0, int Size_axis_1,
                                      UnaryOperator<Float> myFunc) {
```

Unfortunately that will autobox the `float` back and forth.

If performance is a concern you can define a custom interface that is hard-coded to operate on primitive `float`s:

```
interface FloatOperator {
    float apply(float x);
}

public float[][] elemen_wise_function(float[][] x, int Size_axis_0, int Size_axis_1,
                                      FloatOperator myFunc) {
```

In both cases use as:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Size_axis_0; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Size_axis_1; j++) {
            Constructed_array[i][j] = myFunc.apply(x[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Invoke as (example):

```
    elemen_wise_function(array, size0, size1, a -> 1/a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this with Java 6, you can do something like.

```java
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.function.Function;

    public interface MapFunction {
        public float map(float value);
    }

    public static float[][] map2DArray(float[][] floatArrays, MapFunction mapper) {
        final float[][] retval = new float[floatArrays.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < floatArrays.length; i++) {
            float [] floats = floatArrays[i];
            retval[i] = new float[floats.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < floats.length; j++) {
                retval[i][j] = mapper.map(floats[j]);
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Or in Java 8 and you don't mind using Float

```java
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.function.Function;

    public static Float[][] map2DArray(Float[][] floatArrays, Function<Float, Float> mapper) {
        return Arrays.stream(floatArrays).map((Float[] floats) -> 
                Arrays.stream(floats).map(mapper).toArray(Float[]::new)
        ).toArray(Float[][]::new);
    }
```