# Retrieve an array of values assigned to a particular class member from an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, member

Let's say, I have an array of complex data type objects. For example: `FullName[100]`. Each `FullName` object has has 2 class member variables: `String FirstName` and `String LastName`. Now, from this array of `FullName` objects, I want to retrieve an array of `String FirstNames[]`.

How can I do this without the extensive for loop application?

Comment: Basically: no, you can't... There will always be a loop iterating through the array somehow. Maybe you won't see it, as some library hides it behind some clever function calls, but it will be there...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to take a look at [Functional Programming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267297/functional-programming-in-java) and apply `map` function from one of the libraries.

Comment: But behind that, there is a loop down there behind the syntactic sugar, right?

Comment: +1: Closest you can get, but of course it is just hiding the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why avoiding a loop is so important, but you could do it like this:
You could store the names in String arrays and use the Flyweight pattern for your FullName class. So your FullName instances hold a reference to these arrays, and indices that point to the correct elements in the array.

Comment: was just curious to know but now, I will live with the for loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do something like this:

```
public class Test {
    class FullName {
        private String firstName;
        String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
    }


    void main(String... argv) {
        FullName names[] = {new FullName()};
        String[] firstNames = Arrays.stream(names).map(FullName::getFirstName).toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```