# Retrieve array[] of values from ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have an ArrayList of objects. For example: `ArrayList<Person> personList`, where each `Person` has 2 class variables `String name` and `int age`. These variables each have their own getter methods `getName()` and `getAge()`.

What is the simplest way to retrieve an array (or ArrayList) of `int ages[]`?

Note this question is similar to the verbosely titled "[Retrieve an array of values assigned to a particular class member from an array of objects in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473383/retrieve-an-array-of-values-assigned-to-a-particular-class-member-from-an-array)", though without the arbitrary restriction on for-loops, and using an ArrayList instead of an Array.

Comment: Why doesn't the linked question solve your problem?

Comment: The linked question had an arbitrary restrictions on using for-loops, and was retrieving from an an `Array[]` of objects, than using an `ArrayList`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve an array of values assigned to a particular class member from an array of objects in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473383/retrieve-an-array-of-values-assigned-to-a-particular-class-member-from-an-array)

Comment: It's functionally identical though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a target array of the same size as the list then iterate through the list and add each element's `age` to the target array.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I used the following implementation. `int ages[] = new int[personList.size()]; for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) { ages[i] = personList.get(i).getAge(); }`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, I have done a similar implementation below :p

Answer (score 4):

Numerous ways to do this -- here is one.

First get the ages into a list (using a java8 stream), and then convert the list into an array.

```
public int[] getAges() {
    return personList.stream()
        .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
        .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Hint, use `mapToInt`, you can call `toArray` on the stream and get an `int[]` directly.

Comment: @JornVernee ah nice tip! Please feel free to edit my answer with your improvement.

Comment: Is there any way to use streams with a function like `Agent.getResource("angle")`, or would this only work for methods without arguments?

Answer (score 2):

```
Person P1 = new Person("Dev", 25);
Person P2 = new Person("Andy", 12);
Person P3 = new Person("Mark", 20);
Person P4 = new Person("Jon", 33);

ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Person[] { P1, P2, P3, P4 }));
int[] ages = getPersonAges(personList); // [25, 12, 20, 33]
```

---

```
private static int[] getPersonAges(ArrayList<Person> personList) {
    int[] ages = new int[personList.size()];
    int idx = 0;

    for (Person P : personList) {    // Iterate through the personList
        int age = P.getAge();
        ages[idx++] = age;
    }

    return ages;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to one-line the for loop to `ages[idx++] = P.getAge()`?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro No. Those two code segments would be identical. It is acceptable to do either.

Comment: I have written on two lines just to explain that the return type from `P.getAge()` is of type `int` or `autoboxed` to `int`.

Comment: @Steven, remember you can always mark the answer accepted that you found simple and helpful. Thanks :D

Comment: @DevendraLattu Thanks. Typically, I try to avoid rushing to accept an answer so I can avoid the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: The variable name `P` violates the Java naming conventions and naming best practices.