# Java element-wise sum 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, element, addition

Given that I have two arrays in Java, `A` and `B` I want to add the elements, element-wise, which results in a sum array. Doing this implicitly with a loop is easy but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution, perhaps with the guava collections or build in java utils. Or perhaps a python-ish way which makes is easy with list comprehensions.

Example:

```
A   = [2,6,1,4]
B   = [2,1,4,4]
sum = [4,7,5,8]
```

Comment: Using loop is very elegant.

Comment: @Eel Lee did you read the text or only the title?

Comment: like Maroun said, using loop is **the most** elegant way to do any operation on `array`

Comment: @RafaEl Not neccessarily since Java 8.

Comment: ok, ignore my comment. Im going to explore [java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html)

Comment: You might also take a look at this question: [Functional Programming in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267297/functional-programming-in-java)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
private void sum() {
    int a[] = {2, 6, 1, 4};
    int b[] = {2, 1, 4, 4};

    int result[] = new int[a.length];
    Arrays.setAll(result, i -> a[i] + b[i]);
}
```

This will first create `int result[]` of the correct size.

Then with Java 8, released yesterday, the easy part comes:

- You can do an `Arrays.setAll(int[] array, IntUnaryOperator);`
- As `IntUnaryOperator` you can create a lambda mapping the index to the result, in here we choose to map `i` to `a[i] + b[i]`, which exactly produces our sum.
- For very big arrays we can even use `Arrays.parallelSetAll`

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yep, looks like its using lambdas

Comment: That's great!.. Can you explain more about the *mapping*?

Comment: @user3354890:- Then you can go with my answer! :)

Comment: @user3414693 your solution is using loop, in which, OP already mention _"Doing this implicitly with a loop is easy..."_ :(

Comment: I will accept this solution as the answer, as this was the solution I was ultimately looking for even though it is incompatible with java 7. I'll just have to convince the company to upgrade ;-).

Comment: @user3354890 There are far more stronger arguments than this question & answer though, you should look into all Java 8 features and especially the lambdas and `Stream` API are worth it to upgrade, and probably forgetting some other awesome features on the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java8 stream and operation on array like this:

```
//in this example a[] and b[] are same length
int[] a = ...
int[] b = ...
int[] result = new int[a.length];
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
     .forEach(i -> result[i] = a[i] + b[i]);
```

[The answer in java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390463/java-8-stream-and-operation-on-arrays)