# Java 8 Stream and operation on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have just discovered the new Java 8 stream capabilities. Coming from Python, I was wondering if there was now a neat way to do operations on arrays like summing, multiplying two arrays in a "one line pythonic" way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 322, accepted):

There are new methods added to `java.util.Arrays` to convert an array into a Java 8 stream which can then be used for summing etc.

```
int sum =  Arrays.stream(myIntArray).sum();
```

Multiplying two arrays is a little more difficult because I can't think of a way to get the value AND the index at the same time as a Stream operation. This means you probably have to stream over the indexes of the array.

```
//in this example a[] and b[] are same length
int[] a = ...
int[] b = ...
 
int[] result = new int[a.length];

IntStream.range(0, a.length).forEach(i -> result[i] = a[i] * b[i]);
```

---

Commenter [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) points out you can use the `map` method instead of `forEach` like this:

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(i -> a[i] * b[i]).toArray();
```

Comment: `int[] result=IntStream.range(0, a.length).map( i->a[i]* b[i]).toArray();`

Comment: @Holger yes that would work too.  Although you probably want to use `mapToInt` to avoid boxing.

Comment: That last amounts to a simulation of zip where you must preallocate storage for the result.  I wonder why there is no zip in the Streams library?

Comment: According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip#23529010), a zip was in an earlier beta of Java 8, then taken out.  Luckily the poster had the source and it is in the answer.  I have used the code several times and it seems to work very well.

Comment: @dkatzel — Since it's already an IntStream, "map" takes a IntUnaryOperator, so there is no boxing involved.

Answer (score 62):

You can turn an array into a stream by using `Arrays.stream()`:

```
int[] ns = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
Arrays.stream(ns);
```

Once you've got your stream, you can use any of the methods described in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), like `sum()` or whatever. You can `map` or `filter` like in Python by calling the relevant stream methods with a Lambda function:

```
Arrays.stream(ns).map(n -> n * 2);
Arrays.stream(ns).filter(n -> n % 4 == 0);
```

Once you're done modifying your stream, you then call `toArray()` to convert it back into an array to use elsewhere:

```
int[] ns = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] ms = Arrays.stream(ns).map(n -> n * 2).filter(n -> n % 4 == 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 11):

Be careful if you have to deal with large numbers.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
long sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum(); // Wrong: sum == 0
```

The sum above is not `2 * Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
You need to do this in this case.

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToLong(Long::valueOf).sum(); // Correct
```

Answer (score 6):

Please note that Arrays.stream(arr) create a LongStream (or IntStream, ...) instead of Stream so the map function cannot be used to modify the type. This is why .mapToLong, mapToObject, ... functions are provided.

Take a look at [why-cant-i-map-integers-to-strings-when-streaming-from-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028980/why-cant-i-map-integers-to-strings-when-streaming-from-an-array)