# Convert long[] to String using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert a primitive long array like `long[] l1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` to String. This String should have each of these values, separated by a `,` as delimiter.

I want to achieve this by using Java 8's streams. I already got this to work for a `Long[]` array, but for some reason I can't get this to work for the primitive `long[]`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] l1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Long[] l2 = new Long[4];
    l2[0] = new Long(1);
    l2[1] = new Long(2);
    l2[2] = new Long(3);
    l2[3] = new Long(4);
    System.out.println(longToString(l2));
}

public static String longToString(Long... l) {
    String[] x = Arrays.stream(l).map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    String y = Arrays.stream(x).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    return y;
}
```

How can I make this work for `longToString(long... l)` instead of `longToString(Long... l)`?

Also: Did I manage to find the optimal way to convert that, or could this be simplified further? I'm pretty new to Java 8's stream features.

Comment: It doesn't look simpler than `Arrays.toString(l)` ...

Comment: But `Arrays.toString(l)` returns format like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Notice the brackets and spaces after commas. OP might have a requirement where the String should really look like `1,2,3,4`, in which case `Arrays.toString` wouldn't be suitable. If the format doesn't matter then I agree that it would be a better solution than attempting to reinvent the wheel with streams :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to get this working for primitive array is:

```
long[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(l -> ((Long) l).toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29029039/1291150), `Arrays.stream(long[])` creates `LongStream`, not `Stream<Long>`, so you need to use [`mapToObj()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.LongFunction-) method, which will produce `Stream<String>` in this case.

You can make this version even more compact by using `String.valueOf()` instead of `Long.toString()` as Tagir mentions in his comment. Because `String.valueOf` is overloaded for many different types, you won't have to cast the object to Long and just use method reference to `String.valueOf` like this:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

---

Other option is to call [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#boxed--) on the result of `Arrays.stream(long[])` to get `Stream<Long>` on which you can then call `map()`:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper method to convert a `long[]` array to a `Long[]` array.

```
public static String longToString(long[] primitiveArray) {
    Long[] boxedArray = Arrays.stream(primitiveArray).boxed().toArray(size -> new Long[size]);
    return longToString(boxedArray);
}
```

If your goal is not doing it on your own but just pretty printing an array better use `Arrays.toString` as [@alfasin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057429/alfasin) has already mentioned.