# How to perform Lambda expressions and forEach on normal arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

I usually print my ArrayLists such as

```
colors.forEach(color -> System.out.printf("color: %s ", color));
```

But I somehow can't apply this to normal Arrays (`String[] colors`).

How do I apply this expression to normal Arrays?

Comment: Have you tried this: `Stream.of(colors).forEach(System.out::println)`. If you are using printf, you need to od this as `Stream.of(colors).forEach(color -> System.out.printf("color: %s", color)`

Comment: Why use streams for this? It's actually *more* verbose than a `for` loop: `for (String color : colors) System.out.printf("color: %s ", color);`

Comment: It's a sample case. Where I'm applying it, it's less verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need a way to perform Stream operations on arrays.  It's as simple as converting your array to a stream:

```
    Arrrays.stream(colors).forEach(color -> System.out.printf("color: %s ", color));
```

For more info on this see [Java 8 Stream and operation on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390463/java-8-stream-and-operation-on-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

The [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class contains various methods for manipulating arrays, including the static [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) method which returns a sequential [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) with the specified array as its source. For your example, you can use the following code:

```
Arrays.stream(colors).forEach(color -> System.out.printf("color: %s ", color));
```