# Need to create an array method, but unsure if I did it right

Tags: java

I need to create a method with the signature `public double totalRent()`

This method accesses each `Property` object within the array `properties` and sums up the property rent and returns the total amount.
Returns:total rent

So heres my code:

```
public double totalRent()
{

    for(int index = 0; index < property.length; index++)
    {

        int total =+ property[index];
    }
    return totalRent();
}
```

Is this correct? It keeps saying the total variable is not used, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Read the message, `total` is created on each iteration, then immediately destroyed - it's useless. Also, it is `+=` and a `Property` object can't be added to an integer primitive...

Comment: Like @AndrewL. has pointed out, your `total` variable is in the `for` loop. This is an issue of "scope". Variables *defined* (like `total` in this case) in a `for` loop are destroyed at the end of the loop. So, you're assigning a value (`property[index]`) to a new variable (`total`) every time, and then getting rid of that variable (`total`). See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8803674

Comment: In java 8, `long total = Arrays.stream(property).sum();`

Answer (score 2):

Your logic / understanding of the code is a bit off, let's try to fix it:

```
public double totalRent() {

    int total = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < property.length; index++){

        total += (property[index]).getRent(); //assuming the getter here
    }

    return total;
}
```

The first problem here was that you were returning a call to the method itself, thereby creating a [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), and an infinite one at that, since you had no [exit condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination).

What **you want to return** are the **values**, *not* the function itself.
The function defines how you do something, the logical algorithm.

As you also stated, your `IDE` tried to warn you that you were not using the value of `total`. That is because within its scope (you can google this for tutorials and docs, or go [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) ) you never used it, so it was useless.

**The solution** is, you declare the variable **outside** of the `for loop`, so that it is **in** scope and can be returned. 
**Inside** of the `for loop`, you progressively sum all the values, then return.

You will also notice I added `.getRent()` right next to the call to each element of the array. 
That is because you cannot sum objects directly with `+` , you're gonna need to sum the correct field of each one. You can either get the field directly if it is declared as `public` inside of the `Property class`, or with a `getter` (as I did),
*ie.* A method that specifically accesses and `returns` a value from an object.

You can understand more about `getters` and why they're useful by leraning the basic principles of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), or directly from the oracle tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html).

Of course, as some comments suggested, there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390463/java-8-stream-and-operation-on-arrays) to sum all the values in the array, however since this question was specifically about the *mistakes you might have made*, this is more than enough to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are re-creating the same total variable each iteration. The total should be initialized out of the loop, so it doesn't fall out of scope.

Also, you are using =+, but I think you mean +=. += is used to add the latter amount to the former variable.

Also, you are calling the function instead of returning. `return totalRent()` just calls the function again. You should return the variable. (in this case, total)

Something like this:

```
int total = 0;
for(int index = 0; index < properties.length; index++){
  //do stuff
}
return total;
```

Hope this helped, and happy coding!